Turning year to date sum to year to date average
I have a measure that sums the data year to date. I'm now looking to have an average year to date. This is my formula, is there anything I can do here to average instead of sum? Thanks very much.
YTD Sum =
CALCULATE (
    [Headcount Count Calc],
    DATESINPERIOD ( data[Extract Date], MAX ( data[Extract Date] ), -12, MONTH )
)


what about divided by count(month)? or divided by month(max(data[Extract Date])

This worked, thanks very much. Appreciate it.
